# Rails - modeling multiple many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have the following use cases for creating an app that handles courses;

1. Class A is taught by Curt in Bos on 11/1
2. Class A is taught by Curt in NY on 10/19
3. Class A is taught by Jane in SF on 12/5
4. Class A is taught by Jane in Bos on 11/1

What's the best way to create models with many to many relationships for this app?

Should the app have a `teachings` model that belongs to courses, teachers, and locations with a column for the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to create a model for each entity:

- Course
- Teacher
- Location

You then create a join model of sorts which I have choosen to call Lesson:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :locations, through: :lessons
  has_many :teachers, through: :lessons
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :location
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :courses, through: :lessons
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :courses, through: :lessons
  has_many :teachers, through: :lessons
end
```

> I've been playing with this structure for the models but what I
>   noticed is that when submitting the course with a fields_for
>   :locations and a fields_for :instructors, the associations table is
>   creating two separate entries for course_id + instructor_id, course_id
>   + location_id, I would expect a single entry for course_id, instructor_id, location_id. Any thoughts as to why that might happen?

ActiveRecords only ever keeps track of one assocation when you create join models implicitly. To do three way joins you need to create the join model explicitly.

```
<%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>

  <div class="field>
    <% f.label :name %>
    <% f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Lesson plan<legend>
    <%= f.fields_for(:lessons) do |l| %>
      <div class="field>
         <% l.label :name %>
         <% l.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
         <% l.label :starts_at %>
         <% l.datetime_select :starts_at %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
         <% l.label :teacher_ids %>
         <% l.collection_select :teacher_ids, Teacher.all, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
         <% l.label :location_id %>
         <% l.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

`fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes` are powerful tools. However passing attributes nested several levels down can be seen as an anti-pattern of sorts since it creates god classes and unexpected complexity.

A better alternative is to use AJAX to send separate requests to create teachers and locations. It gives a better UX, less validation headaches and better application design.

Comment: thanks for this - I've been playing with this structure for the models but what I noticed is that when submitting the course with a `fields_for :locations` and a `fields_for :instructors`, the `associations` table is creating two separate entries for course_id + instructor_id, course_id + location_id, I would expect a single entry for course_id, instructor_id, location_id. Any thoughts as to why that might happen?

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong. When the joining model is not just a 2-way join model you cannot create it implicitly as ActiveRecord only can keep track of one relation. See my edit.

Comment: thanks for the info, I wasn't aware Rails had limitations with three way joins. So the only way to do this is to create the location and teacher separately and then associate them using a collection select?

Comment: Yes. You can nest  `fields_for(:teachers)` inside `fields_for(:lessons)` but it is a anti-pattern.

Comment: Interesting, I will play around with your recommendation of making this a three step process. For including dates of each course, would you recommend adding a column to the lessons table?

Comment: Nicely done I get the point now of separating these into discrete objects that can then be associated with each other. Thanks for the feedback guys!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Here is how I would model these relationships. Let's say you have a `Teacher` model, a `Course` model and a `TeacherCourses` model that will be our join table between teachers and courses:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :courses, through: :teacher_courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :teachers, through: :teacher_courses
end

class TeacherCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

Your `teacher_courses` table would also have location attribute differentiating a record from the same course/teacher combo:

```
create_table :teacher_courses do |t|
  t.integer :teacher_id
  t.integer :course_id
  t.string :location
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: I would still use a seperate table for locations for data normalization.

Comment: Not sure i'm following. How would that be beneficial? I'm sure you're right just curious about the tradeoff

Comment: Well instead of having houndreds of strings with different variations on `D-Wing, University of Derpville, Derpville, DERPLAND` you point to a single normalized record. It also makes it straight forward to add features like for example geolocation.

Comment: @Cyzanfar the purpose is to be able to reuse a location as it can have many courses. Your solution seems to suggest that the location would have to be entered in each time a course is created.